# File types in EFI partition

Tags: macos, partition, efi, file-extensions

In El Capitan, I mounted the EFI partition using `sudo diskutil mount /dev/disk0s1` and instead of finding apps that I can run, I found `.scap`, `.smc`, `.epm`, and `.efi` files. What are these? The reason I ask here is because (for example) a search for ".smc file" yields "It's an SNES ROM file".

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect that you're going to find apps that you can run since everything in the EFI partition is presumably dealing with the hardware directly and doesn't conform to a UNIX/BSD/OSX application model. Instead, it is a bit of a mini-OS that has enough drivers to support booting from various devices (disk, USB, network, etc.) before handing control over to the "booted" operating system.

That all being said, I would imagine that the files you'd find there would be a combination of the raw boot code (i.e. initial bootstrap of UEFI "mini-OS"), the main UEFI kernel, various device drivers for the hardware onboard, NVRAM storage and possibly a driver/API that the OS can access to communicate with the above (e.g. setting nvram values).

That all being said, I'm sure there are better resources out there on the internet to explain what the exact files are, but I would suspect that there is extremely limited utility for end users since it is all very hardware specific ultimately.

Comment: In Yosemite I was able to run an app that allowed me to set/change my firmware password by mounting the EFI partition. Is the change part of SIP, maybe?

Comment: I know there is something in the recovery partition for firmware passwords; I suppose if you mounted the recovery partition then you would be able to run that application from OSX. I'll admit I don't know exactly it is doing on the EFI partition, but I'd assume it is ultimately stored in NVRAM.

Comment: Wait... does that mean if I clear the NVRAM my firmware password would go away?